# SaveChanges not doing anything in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a WCF which calls EF functions.

When I invoke the method from the client to insert a user nothing happens.

This is the method I am invoking :

```
public void insertData(Users pUser)
{
    using (var context = new AMTEntitiesContainer())
    {
        var User = context.Users.Add(pUser);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong in this code?

Comment: Are you sure that the user is being passed to the method correctly (i.e. when you debugged it)?

Comment: The user has some null properties..but I allowed them to be null,I am passing only user name and the ID is set to be autogenerated

Comment: Could you please post your `AMTEntitiesContainer` class, then?

Comment: do debug, trace it - do you get errors - do you have, are sure that your connection points to where you expect it to be?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I see wrong is var User is not needed.  Simply use context.Users.Add(pUser); and save the changes.

The other possibility is that AMTEntitiesContainer is not a proper DbContext.  Without seeing your AMTEntitiesContainer class it would be hard to figure that out though.

Comment: `var user =` will not prevent `SaveChanges` from working. Your other possibility would be better served as a comment.

Comment: The question was 'Is there anything wrong with this code?' the answer is that var user is not needed, so I did effectively answer the question but if you do not agree I can delete my answer.  His problem is not in this code.